Robust Reexport a bash variable
Is there any way to export a variable that is passed as a shell variable?
setup.sh:
if [[ -z "$MYVAR" ]]; then
    MYVAR="default"
fi

export MYVAR=$MYVAR
export MYVAR2=$MYVAR

% . ./setup.sh
% echo $MYVAR
default
% echo $MYVAR2
default

% MYVAR=other . ./setup.sh
% echo $MYVAR 

% echo $MYVAR2
other

When MYVAR is defined before sourcing the script, it will not be set.
If you separate the definition and the source command with a semicolon then it does work:
% MYVAR=other; . ./setup.sh
% echo $MYVAR 
other
% echo $MYVAR2
other

Someone pointed this out in a comment to a question I unfortunately deleted before realising I still have issues. Not including the semicolon when defining a variable inline is pretty common, and so other users of this script will quite likely make the same mistake I did. How can I ensure that the exported variables are set in both cases?

totally OT, but: "Someone pointed this out in a comment to a question I unfortunately deleted before realising I still have issues." why would you delete a question where all the issues have been resolved? if everybody did that, stackoverflow would be a sad and barren place. (or am I misunderstanding something?)

Why don't you simply write export MYVAR, without providing a value? Then the current value is the one of the environment variable.

@umläute My original question was closed as a duplicate, and I started to rebut that assertion before I realised I'd made a mistake. I deleted it as I thought the close was valid, before later realising that there's still a valid question to be answered! Undelete apparently isn't a thing.

Prefixing an assignment to a command changes the environment for the command only. See Simple Command Expansion in man bash:

If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the current shell environment.  Otherwise, the variables are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell  environment.

This means that not using the semicolon changes the environment for ., i.e. it sees $MYVAR as an already exported variable. You can test it by prepending the following line to setup.sh:
export -p | grep MYVAR

For some reason, when the sourced script ends, the value is not propagated back to the shell. I've found a workaround, though: in the script, unset the variable and then export it with the new value. Again, for reasons unknown to me, export -n or declare +x is not enough.
if [[ -z $MYVAR ]] ; then
    MYVAR=default
fi
v=$MYVAR
unset MYVAR
export MYVAR=$v
export MYVAR2=$v


The behavior you observe is related to an intentional Bash deviation from POSIX shell semantics.
POSIX specifies that variable assignments appearing in a command designating a shell built-in remain in effect when execution of the built-in completes.  That would include the MYVAR=other in

MYVAR=other . ./setup.sh


On the other hand, the Bash manual documents


Assignment statements preceding POSIX special builtins persist in the shell environment after the builtin completes.


among the differences between its POSIX mode and its standard mode.  (In other words, it doesn't ordinarily do that.)  I find that sourcing your script in POSIX mode indeed has the effect you intend, giving MYVAR the export attribute (as opposed to MYVAR remaining merely as an un-exported shell variable, which it would do in POSIX mode if the script did not export it).
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1
$ echo "${MYVAR-unset}"
unset
$ MYVAR=other . ./setup.sh
$ echo "${MYVAR-unset}"
other
$ bash -c 'echo "${MYVAR-unset}"'
other
$ 

I would be inclined to guess that clobbering the script's export of the variable is an unintended side effect of the implementation of Bash's standard-mode semantics.  In that mode, it does not ordinarily preserve the values set on the built-ins' command lines. That requires actively reverting command-line variable assignments and reassignments, and apparently it does not make an exception for variables whose values or export status is modified by the . command itself. I judge that to be an unintended oversight, because Bash does make an exception for the export command itself:
$ echo "${foo-unset}"
unset
$ foo=bar export foo
$ echo "${foo-unset}"
bar
$ bash -c 'echo "${foo-unset}"'
bar
$

(Note the distinction between foo=bar export foo above, which is one command, and foo=bar; export foo, which is two.)
One workaround, then, would be to put Bash into POSIX mode before sourcing the script.  You can even do that on the . command line itself:
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 MYVAR=other . ./setup.sh

If you don't otherwise want to be in POSIX mode, then you would need to unset POSIXLY_CORRECT afterward.  If you're uncertain whether you want to be in POSIX mode (for example, if you want to remain in whichever mode you started in, but you don't know in advance which that will be) then you would need to add extra code to account for that.

Thanks for the explanation. I didn't test your solution but I'm sure it works. Gave an upvote, but I will accept the other answer, as your solution still requires the user of the script to be aware of the issue, whereas the other answer does not.
